# setRgb in java for tif buffered image loses its coordinate information

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have a program in java where tif file read in source buffered image and then this buffered image is replicated as destination buffered image.
When I write this buffered image on disk, the image loses its coordinate information.
What can be done so that coordinate information is not lost?

My code is:

```
/* Check if imageType if tif */
if (imageType.equalsIgnoreCase(TIFF)) {
    bufferedImageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
}
BufferedImage destination = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                bufferedImageType);
/* Loop to cover all pixels */
for (int width = 0; width < source.getWidth(); width++) {
    /* Loop to cover all lines */
    for (int height = 0; height < source.getHeight(); height++) {
        destination.setRGB(width, height, source.getRGB(width, height));
    }
}
file = new File(TEMP_DIR + TEMP_FILE_NAME + "tif");
ImageIO.write(destination, "tif", file);
```

Comment: *"coordinate information"*  DYM the location/date that the photo was taken?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but nevertheless...

If you are talking about all the header data that is lost during this process then you can use Apache Commons Imaging to copy the header from the source image file to the destination image file.

Here is an example:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/xref-test/org/apache/commons/imaging/formats/jpeg/exif/ExifRewriteTest.html